# The nginx upstream configuration do not distinguish domain

Tags: javascript, nginx, webserver

in my nginx.conf, there I configured the upstream `nodenuxt1` and `nodenuxt2`:

```
http {
    ...
    upstream nodenuxt1 {
        server 127.0.0.1:3000; # 
        keepalive 64;
    }

    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name nodenuxt1.com  www.nodenuxt1.com;
        location / {
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;  
            proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Nginx-Proxy true;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
            proxy_pass http://nodenuxt1; 
        }
    }


    upstream nodenuxt2 {
    server 127.0.0.1:3002; 
    keepalive 64;
    }

    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  nodenuxt2.com www.nodenuxt2.com;

        location / {
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;  
            proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Nginx-Proxy true;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
            proxy_pass http://nodenuxt2;       
        }

        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }

    }
    ......
```

then I started the `localhost:3000` and `localhost:3002`, each prefer to `/www/wwwroot/www.nodenuxt1.com` and `/www/wwwroot/www.nodenuxt2.com`.

and run pm2:

```
# pm2 start npm --name "proj_nuxt" -- run start
```

```
# pm2 list
┌────┬────────────────────┬──────────┬──────┬───────────┬──────────┬──────────┐
│ id │ name               │ mode     │ ↺    │ status    │ cpu      │ memory   │
├────┼────────────────────┼──────────┼──────┼───────────┼──────────┼──────────┤
│ 0  │ proj_nuxt          │ fork     │ 217… │ online    │ 0%       │ 30.7mb   │
└────┴────────────────────┴──────────┴──────┴───────────┴──────────┴──────────┘
```

but however, when I access `www.demo1.com` and `www.demo2.com`, them all point to `www.demo1.com`

Answer (score -1):

I understood that you just want to distinguish domain to your suitable application as below:

1. [www.demo1.com](http://www.demo1.com) will point to the app at HTTP://127.0.0.1:3003
2. [www.demo2.com](http://www.demo2.com) will point to the app at HTTP://127.0.0.1:3002

The below config work for me (not using upstream):

```
server {
    listen       80 default_server;
    listen       [::]:80 default_server;

    server_name  demo1.com  www.demo1.com;
    root         /usr/share/nginx/html;

    include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

    location / {
      proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3003;
    }
}

server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  demo2.com www.demo2.com;
    root         /usr/share/nginx/html;

    location / {
       proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3002;
    }
}
```

Comment: but you did not use the `upstream`.

Comment: I just give an alternative way of configuring Nginx to achieve the same result as you expected.

Ok, so I do config my Nginx exactly like your above config and it just works.
So the problem does not come from Nginx, It comes from another stuff.

In my case, I have to start two applications at localhost:3002 and localhost:3003. Both of my application is controlled by PM2. So my pm2 list contains 2 processes (one at localhost:3002 and another at localhost:3003).

I don't understand the part that you started localhost:3002 and localhost:3003, then you start another process using PM2.

Comment: What exactly what you do when you start localhost:3002? Do you use PM2 to start or something else?

Comment: You see the `pm2 list` only display one.